# Saved directory cannot be changed

Tags: python

Saved directory cannot be changed.

I wrote the following code:

```
import shutil
with open("test.wav", 'wb') as f:
     shutil.move("app/", "/Users/xxx/Downloads")
```

My application name is app,now test.wav is under `app/` .But I wanna save the data under `/Users/xxx/Downloads`.So I wrote this code, but it did not work. I think I should use the f variable to change the save directory, but I dont understand how to fix this. What should I do to achieve my ideal system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil
with open("test.wav", 'wb') as f:
    # DO your operations 
    f.close()   # You need to close as you open in wb
shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the filename as well:

```
import shutil
with open("bhushan.txt", 'wb') as f:
    shutil.move(str(f.name), "/home/bhushanpant/")
```

Hope this helps :)